# JavaFX Изменение картинки

Tags: java, javafx, изображения

Поскольку только учусь, то не совсем понимаю как работает.
Вообщем есть сцена которая заливается текстурой:

```
#default{
    -fx-background-image: url("icon/floor.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}
```

Теперь я захотел поменять тесктуру. Я написал код, где я выбираю нужную текстуру и она записывается на место "icon/floor.png". Т.е. делаю

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(source), Paths.get(target), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Но изменения происходят только после перезагрузки приложения :(.
Можно ли как то переинициализировать начальную картинку "icon/floor.png" ?

Comment: Предполагаю, что использование кастомного стиля и переназначение его после загрузки картинки может помочь, но надо проверять.